# MediaPlayer issue: element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc

Tags: android, media-player, javadoc, android-mediaplayer

Not technically 'Problem' (the code compiles) but crashes when I run it.
/////////////////////////

> android.media.MediaPlayer
>   Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.
>   ////////////////////////

All I'm doing in the code is this:

```
final  MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(FrontLever.this, R.raw.airhorn);
```

I'm new at this so please dumb down what I need to do.  Stupid pain in the butt.

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: I get exactly: android.media.MediaPlayer Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.

Comment: That's not an error; that Eclipse telling you that there is no documentation.

Comment: right, which is why I said "Not technically 'Problem'"  Either way, I need some help fixing it so my program will work.

Comment: This message does not affect your program in any way.

Comment: I disagree.  When I put that one line of code in my program it crashes but when I comment it out the program runs fine.

Comment: That message has nothing to do with the crash.  Use the debugger to read the exception.